# writing jasmine tests for Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Upon load of my controller in angular I perform a bunch of initialization. Some initialization are local while others are via http calls.

while writing testcases, in order to check whether variables are initialized to what they should be 
i am currently initialing the controller in every test-case like below:

```
describe('on-load',function(){

  it('should initialize scope.player to xyz if some-dependency is abc',function(){
    createController();
    expect( .... );
  }

  it('should initialize scope.player to mno if some-dependency is def',function(){
    createController();
    expect( .... );
  }

  it('should initialize scope.canvas.size to 900',function(){
    createController();
    expect( .... );
  }

}
```

Is this the correct way of thinking about writing jasmine tests for angular controllers ?

Comment: You havent actually written any test.If you need to test in isolation,mock your dependencies.That's unit testing 101.

Comment: For sake of clarity i have shown high-level code here. I do mock dependencies in beforeEach blocks. My question is "Are controllers to be created in each it block or just once" ?

Comment: use beforeEach hooks for fixtures.it are the place where one writes expectations.

Comment: I have no clue what you are saying. can you be more lucid pls ?

Comment: use beforeEach() for test fixtures, and it() to set expectations.If you need to create something,do it in beforeEach() callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The controller will be created in each `it` block and I think it's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct or more correct way, it all depends what you want to test …

For example, if you have something like this:

```
angular.contoller('controller', function controller() {
    this.init = function() {}
    this.init();
}
```

Example with stubbing / mocking `$http.get()` that is called directly in controller: http://moduscreate.com/unit-testing-w-angularjs/. Some note – instead of assign function to variable **createControlle** you can extract it outside **beforeEach** block.

Without stubbing method `.init()` in section `beforeEach()` and instantiate controller in each **it** section there is no way to test methods like `.init()`.
Because if you are going to create controller in **beforeEach** it is to late to stub its internal methods.